# Why am I getting this error when trying to call a SVM for doing OCR?

Tags: r, machine-learning, ocr, svm

am following the book Machine Learning with R by Brett Lantz and trying take the OCR with SVMs exercise step by step. This is my code:

```
letters <- read.csv("letterdata.csv")
str(letters)

letters_train <- letters[1:16000, ]
letters_test <- letters[16001:20000, ]

library(kernlab)
```

When trying to use the command:

```
letter_classifier <- ksvm(letter ~ ., data = letters_train, kernel = "vanilladot")
```

I get the error:

```
No Support Vectors found. You may want to change your parameters
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> ksvm -> ksvm -> .local -> ksvm -> ksvm -> .local
```

My code looks exactly like in the book and I installed the needed packages.

Comment: We need more information. What did `str(letters)` return. Without knowing anything about your data, it is impossible to say.

Comment: Does the book may any comments about seeds?

Comment: Just tested it myself, same error. It's possible there was an update in a package (or R) after the book was released causing the error.

Comment: I got it! @RaphaelS was right, all I had to do was add `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` when reading the csv.
Thanks for your input everyone!

Comment: Ah, yup that exact update has caused me so many problems, good catch!

Comment: You may want to consider opening an issue on their (kenlab) GitHub as this is actually something they should fix from their side.